# Site column used in second list shows row number

Tags: sharepoint, row-number, site-column

We are using SharePoint 2013. Hopefully someday we will upgrade but for now we are stuck with it. 
One List we have is our department's Servers. It contains a site column (server name). This list utilizes another site column, Applications. We want to identify the applications used on which server. 
The problem is that the Server List is showing the *row number* of the application(s) selected, not the Application Name! I see many solutions on how to show the row number. I don't want row number. We have over 600 applications and I need to see the title, not row number. 
In the Applications List, there is no Index column. 
What can I do to show the actual Application Name in the Server list instead of the row number of the application?

[image: Site Column row numbers show]

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Go to your Servers list settings (From Ribbon or from Site Contents)
2. Under `Columns` click your `Applications` column (type Lookup)
3. In `Additional column settings` section [image: Applications list] and select column from Applications list which you would like to see.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you! That took care of it right away. I am very grateful. Thanks again.